# upload image files with specific directory structure to amazon s3 django

Tags: django, amazon-s3, image-uploading, django-models

I have a django model that uploads the files to local folder by creating some folder structure according to model name

**utils.py**

```
def asset_upload(instance, filename):
    ctype = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(instance)
    model = ctype.model
    app = ctype.app_label    

    if model == 'product':
        # Assets for a Product
        user_id = instance.user.fs_uid
        product_id = instance.id
        output = 'user%s/product%s/assets/%s' % (user_id, product_id, filename)

    elif model == 'category':
        # Assets for a Product
        user_id = instance.user.fs_uid
        product_id = instance.id
        output = 'user%s/category%s/assets/%s' % (user_id, product_id, filename)

    else:
        raise NotImplementedError("Unsupported model for Image Upload")

    return output
```

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 36)
    description = models.TextField(max_length = 2000)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to = utils.asset_upload, null = True, max_length = 250)
    picture.allow_tags = True
```

**forms.py**

```
class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
```

**views.py**

```
def product_creation(request):
    product_form = ProductForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        product_form = ProductForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if product_form.is_valid():
            obj = product_form.save(commit=False)
            obj........ = ....
            obj.save()
            return redirect(reverse('product_detail', args=[obj.id]))
    return render_to_response('products/product.html',
                                    { 'product_form':product_form,},
                                    context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

So from the above code, i can able to upload the images successfully to `media` folder  like

```
/media/user235/product269/assets/buscuits_butter.png
/media/user235/product269/assets/choclate_pie.png
```

But now i want to store the above images to `Amazon s3` instead of my local file system

so by googling i found some code like [here](http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/video?name=2680000&fromSeriesID=268)

```
def store_in_s3(filename, content):
    conn = S3Connection(settings.ACCESS_KEY, settings.PASS_KEY)
    b = conn.create_bucket("bucket_name")
    mime = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)[0]
    k = Key(b)
    k.key = filename
    k.set_metadata("Content-Type", mime)
    k.set_contents_from_string(content)
    k.set_acl("public-read")
```

So from the above function if i send my file path along with content then i hope images will be saved in to amazon s3(by providing all the credentials)

But i am `confused` on how to implement/send the file(with the some directory path) in to this function.

I tried to make the `upload_to = None` in models, but encountered errors

```
product: "picture": FileFields require an "upload_to" attribute.
```

Also now as we know, want to avoid saving file to localfolder, and save it to amazon bucket

So can anyone please let me know how to `hook/re arrange` my above code to upload the images with the file directory structure i am generating according to model structure as above

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Django's [`File Storage API`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/storage/) especially the [S3 Storage](http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html).

I wouldn't pass a function as a upload_to keyword. You could consider creating inheriting `ImageField` and write your own naming method.

Answer (score 0):

***What you can try.. Jump to point 5 for specific folder aiming during upload.***

***1. Make sure you have the right S3 Permissions and Policy in place. Access 'Policy' via permissions tab in AWS S3 console for your specific bucket.***

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<your_bucket_name>/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Statement2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<your_bucket_name>/images/"
        }
    ]
}
```

***2. Install WhiteNoiseMiddleware & django-storages in your project environment.***

```
pip install whitenoise
pip install django-storages
```

***3. Add the following to `MIDDLEWARE=` in `settings.py`***

```
'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
```

***4. Following additions in `settings.py` are required to handle URLs from S3 correctly. The handling is done by django middleware & django-storages automatically***

```
STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'
MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'

AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % os.environ['BUCKET_NAME']
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ['AWS_KEY']
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ['AWS_ACC_KEY']
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ['BUCKET_NAME']
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3StaticStorage'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join (BASE_DIR, 'static/images/')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join (BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATIC_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, STATICFILES_LOCATION)
MEDIA_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, MEDIAFILES_LOCATION)
```

***5. For aiming uploads into a precise S3 Bucket folder. (Additional)***

In setting.py set media root:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join (BASE_DIR, 'static/images/')
```

In models.py use `ImageFiled` and add `upload_to=` takes in a folder name and creates it with the first upload!:

```
image_variable = models.ImageField(null=True, default="{default_filename)", upload_to='uploads/')
```

Reference: [django-storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html) , [whiteNoiseMiddelware](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/), [S3 Access Troubleshooting](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-access-file-folder/)

Comment: Not working for me after setting MEDIA_ROOT. Any ideas?